# Insert values if they don't already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LikesRefined] (userA,userB)                  
SELECT l1.[user],l1.likes
FROM [dbo].[Like] l1
inner join [dbo].[Like] l2 on l2.[user] = l1.likes and l2.likes = l1.[user]
WHERE l1.[user] < l1.likes
```

I'm inserting values `userA`,`userB` if there is a match in `[dbo].[Like]` into `[dbo].[LikesRefined]`

How can I only insert records that don't already exist in `[dbo].[LikesRefined]` ?

Comment: check if the record exists first

Comment: You can try MERGE() function

Comment: `AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.LikesRefined WHERE userA = l1.[user] AND UserB = l1.likes)`

Comment: @Lamak NOT EXISTS doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the merge as well. but performance could be an issue because merge forces you to do matched/unmatched so you'd be updating the records that exist even though its not needed.

```
 SELECT l1.[user],l1.likes
 INTO #recordsToInsert
 FROM [dbo].[Like] l1
 inner join [dbo].[Like] l2 on l2.[user] = l1.likes and l2.likes = l1.[user]
 WHERE l1.[user] < l1.likes


MERGE LikesRefined AS T
USING #recordsToinsert AS S
ON (T.userA = S.user AND T.userB=s.likes)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
THEN INSERT(userA, userB) VALUES(S.user, S.likes)
WHEN MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
UPDATE T SET userA=user,userB=likes WHERE userA=user and userB=likes;

DROP TABLE #recordsToInsert
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just add the NOT EXISTS to your where clause and check the LikesRefined table to determine whether it exists or not first.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LikesRefined] (userA,userB)                  
SELECT l1.[user],l1.likes
FROM [dbo].[Like] l1
inner join [dbo].[Like] l2 on l2.[user] = l1.likes and l2.likes = l1.[user]
WHERE l1.[user] < l1.likes
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
               FROM dbo.LikesRefined 
               WHERE userA = l1.[user] AND UserB = l1.likes)
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO [dbo].[LikesRefined] (userA,userB)
                  
SELECT l1.[user],l1.likes
FROM [dbo].[Like] l1
inner join [dbo].[Like] l2 on l2.[user] = l1.likes and l2.likes = l1.[user]
WHERE l1.[user] < l1.likes
AND NOT EXISTS(
 SELECT 1 FROM dbo.LikesRefined 
 WHERE userA = l1.[user] or userA = l1.likes
 AND userB = l1.[user] or userB = l1.likes
 )`



It's not working, returns 0 rows when I insert new data into the likes table.

Comment: That NOT EXISTS is not the same as what I have you added code with the OR.

Comment: I have to add in the `or` because when they are inserted userA from the likes table could be inserted into either of the columns of the likesRefined table. So I'm checking if userA is in column A or B and UserB is column A or B .

Answer (score 0):

Try this please

```
if not exists (select 1 from [dbo].[LikesRefined] where (userA, userB) in
(select l1.[user],l1.likes
FROM [dbo].[Like] l1
inner join [dbo].[Like] l2 on l2.[user] = l1.likes and l2.likes = l1.[user]
WHERE l1.[user] < l1.likes))
begin

--- insert query

end;
```

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/IkdVjo2.png

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[LikesRefined] (userA,userB)

(SELECT l1.[user],l1.likes
FROM [dbo].[Like] l1
LEFT JOIN LikesRefined
ON l2.[user] = l1.likes AND l2.likes = l1.[user]
WHERE l2.user IS NULL)
```

The select statement will return what is in the Like table where the corresponding record in LikesRefined is null (i.e., non-existant). Just make sure you choose a normally non-nullable field in LikesRefined.